# Why "work" in this sentence has no article?

Tags: articles, paraphrasing

In [this article](https://esl.about.com/od/writingintermediate/a/l_spell.htm) I found this sentence:

> Spelling words in English is **challenging work**.

I want to use it in my article, but don't know how to paraphrase it. Moreover, is it a grammatical sentence? Why "challenging work" has no article?

What about these sentences?

- Spelling words in English is **a challenging work (task)**.
- Spelling words in English is **challenging**.

Comment: We don't use *a work* to mean a task, only to mean a thing created (a work by Shakespeare). *Challenging work* is an activity, like spelling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Spelling English words is challenging work.

*Work* is a non-count noun here.  It refers abstractly to work in general, not concretely to individual, countable instances of work.

The noun phrase *challenging work* is indefinite, but you only use the indefinite article *a(n)* with count nouns.  This noun phrase doesn't need an article.

So the sentence is fine the way it is.

> *Spelling English words is a challenging work.

This would be fine if *work* were a count noun in this context, but it's not.

This sentence is not fine, so I've marked it with a *.

> Spelling English words is a challenging task.

In contrast, *task* works fine as a count noun in this context.  It refers concretely to individual, countable units of work.

This sentence is fine.

> Spelling English words is challenging.

Here, you've replaced the noun phrase *challenging work* with the adjective phrase *challenging*.  Adjective phrases don't need determiners, so of course there's no article.

This sentence is fine.